# Antenna polarization and loss factor

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, electric-field, far-field

I am trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

I know that in the +z direction:

**linear polarization requires the field vector to have:**

1. one component OR
2. two orthogonal linear components that are in phase or 180 degrees (or multiples of 180) out of phase.

**Circular polarization requires:**

1. field must have two orthogonal linear components AND
2. the two components must have the same magnitude AND
3. the phase difference must be odd multiples of 90 degrees.

**Polarization loss factor:**

\$ PLF = |\hat{\rho_w} \cdot  \hat{\rho_a}| ^{2}\$

**In the +z direction**

for linear:

\$\Delta \phi = \phi_y - \phi_x = n\pi, n = 0,1,2,3...\$

**for RHCP:**

\$|E_x| = |E_y|\$

\$\Delta \phi = \phi_y - \phi_x = -(\frac{1}{2} + n) \pi, n = 0,1,2,3...\$

**for LHCP:**

\$|E_x| = |E_y|\$

\$\Delta \phi = \phi_y - \phi_x = (\frac{1}{2} + n)  \pi, n = 0,1,2,3...\$

**Therefore:**

For linear polarization: \$\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}\$

For RHCP: \$\phi = \frac{3\pi}{2}\$

For LHCP: \$\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}\$

For PLF:

\$\hat{\rho_a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a_x} +  \hat{a_y})\$

\$\hat{\rho_w} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{sin^2(\phi) + cos^2(\phi)}}(\hat{a_x}sin(\phi) +  \hat{a_y}jcos(\phi))  = (\hat{a_x}sin(\phi) +  \hat{a_y}jcos(\phi))\$

\$ PLF = |\hat{\rho_w} \cdot  \hat{\rho_a}| ^{2} = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a_x} + \hat{a_y}) \cdot (\hat{a_x}sin(\phi) +  \hat{a_y}jcos(\phi))|^{2}\$

And im not sure where to go from there for the PLF.

Are any of these answers correct? What am I doing right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have been mixing the following:

- phase difference between the two field components, and
- the angle \$ \phi \$ in the given wave expression

As you know, to have a ***linear polarization***, we must have only one component of the field, or two components with 0 or 180 degrees phase shift.

The two given components are: \$ \sin(\phi) \$  & \$ j \cos(\phi) \$. Because of the existence  of \$(j)\$, we can NOT find an angle \$\phi\$ to make the phase shift 180. This will require to generate an imaginary value for \$\sin(\phi)\$ or \$\cos(\phi)\$. Then, we have only the choice of making the field of one component. That is it, we seek \$\sin(\phi)\$ or \$\cos(\phi)\$ equal to zero. This happens at \$\phi = 0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2\$. Notice that the angle \$\phi\$ is limited in \$[0,2\pi]\$.

For circular polarization, either left or right handed, you need to solve  \$\sin(\phi)\$ \$= \pm \$ \$\cos(\phi)\$ to have the circular polarization condition. This occurs at \$ \phi = \pi/4,5\pi/4 \$ for left hand CP and at \$ \phi = 3\pi/4, 7\pi/4 \$ for right hand CP.

For the second point in your question, the polarization loss factor will be found at all \$ \phi \$:
$$PLF = |\hat{\rho}_w .\hat{\rho}_a|^2 $$
where
$$ \hat{\rho}_w = \sin(\phi)\hat{x} + j\cos{\phi}\hat{y}  $$
$$ \hat{\rho}_a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{x}+\hat{y})$$
Substituting gives:
$$PLF = \bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\phi)+j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(\phi)\bigg|^2$$
Then,
$$PLF = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\phi)+\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}$$
So, at all \$\phi\$, the polarization loss factor will always be equal to 1/2. This is reasonable since the antenna is aligned at mid angle between the \$x\$ & \$y\$ axes, while the incoming wave has two components that are always orthogonal in space.